# Project on MIPS pipelined processor

Tags: mips, vhdl, pipelining

Okay this question is more of a discussion . I have this project of implementing a `pipelined` `MIPS` processor in `VHDL` .

I am fully acquainted with the concepts of pipelining but I have never implemented it with `VHDL` . What are some good resources to learn  implementation of `pipelined processors` in `VHDL` .

I need a head start ?

Comment: Hmmm..... that sounds like a pretty large assignment…  For a start you should be sure you known most of Peter J. Ashenden book "The Designer's Guide to VHDL".  Also, define a coding style, at least for the synthesizable part of the code, with at least identifier naming where the stage number for the signal is part of the signal names, e.g. stall_s3, so it is easy to see if an expression uses valid signals.  However, first of all you may want to check out OpenCores… It takes time to build a reliable CPU from scratch ;-)

Comment: Actually @MortenZdk I am not new to VHDL . I have made a lot of simple projects in VHDL but the processor as a whole is a little mind-boggling . I cant figure where to start and are there VHDL codes ( open source ) available for pipelined processors . I googled a lot but couldn't find anything useful .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a book [Digital Design and Computer Architecture](http://books.google.com/books?id=5X7JV5-n0FIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by David Harris and Sarah Harris.  See Chapter 7 on Microarchitecture.  7.5 talks about pipelining using a MIPS processor model.  7.6 shows Verilog and VHDL code implementing.  It's a textbook and there's a second edition, where the HDL examples from the companion web site are VHDL and SystemVerilog apparently.  Looking through the VHDL code there doesn't appear to be emphasis on pipeline registers, rather on building blocks.  The figures in 7.5 should be a big help and can be downloaded from the companion site as well.

On the opencores website there's  the  [Ion - MIPS(tm) compatible CPU :: Overview](http://opencores.org/project,ion), where you can download the VHDL model (after registering) for an R3000 compatible core.  The pipeline stages are apparent in mips_cpu.vhdl, with names preceded by their pipeline stage (e.g. p1_alu_flags).  There are testbenches for exercising the model and it's parts.  There's information on tools so you can generate software to run on it.

There's GeorgiaTech's ECE 3055a course (see  [EE 3055 Outline](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~copeland/jac/3055-00/outline.html) in 2000 where 4 weeks was devoted to Pipelining. If you look at the  [Lab-2 Help](http://www.csc.gatech.edu/~copeland/3055-00/lab/lab-2/lab2_step1.html), the exercise is to add pipelining into an RTL model in VHDL.  The first stage is shown.  What you can get out of this is that you can add pipelining to a behavior model, implied in the book above, as well.  You can download the  [VHDL Synthesis Models](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/ITRANED/CDROM/SOFT.HTM)  (try  [MIPSSYN.TAR](http://www.ece.gatech.edu/users/hamblen/ITRANED/CDROM/MIPSSYN.TAR)).  The instruction simulator referred to can be found here: [Index of ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/pub/spim/](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/pub/spim/).  A description of [Laboratory Assignment 2](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~copeland/jac/3055-00/lab/lab2.html) is also available.  Google is just full of clues on this and the MIPS model was described in [A VHDL Synthesis Model of the MIPS Processor for use in Computer Architecture Laboratories](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/ITRANED/CDROM/INDEX.HTM).  The Home page [ECE 3055 Computer Architecture and Operating Systems J. Hamblen](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/3055/).  See The Home page [32-bit MIPS VHDL Model](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/3055/mips32.zip)  for a set of files used in the class used with Altera tools.  Contains the VHDL source code.  The instruction simulator would be used in verification.

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a picture of the hardware you want.

If you already know VHDL and know a limited set of coding templates such as Logic gates (and, or, not, xor), adders (+), multipliers (*), Multiplexor (think case statement), Statemachine, and flip-flop you are all set.  Make sure to learn the peculiarities of the operator result sizing - see VHDL Math Tricks of the Trade for help at:  http://www.synthworks.com/papers

Next code your picture.  Write a process or assignment for each piece in your hardware picture and connect them together with signals.

The one process stuff and using variables that some prefer is just a refinement. Get your project done now.  Focus on refinement and determining your favorite coding style later.  Even now my coding style is still evolving.  Accept that it will never be perfect.  Code is not art.  Done and brute force is better than elegant and still debugging.  P.S. Variables are fine.  For some though they make it harder to see the hardware implications, so I don't recommend them for getting started.  If you find them easy, go for it - but don't say I did now caution you.

Understand that synthesis tools are fussy about coding styles for hardware creation.  So 
**simulate** and **synthesize** each block as you go so you learn both what works in simulation and **synthesis** - that way at the end you do not have lots of corrections during synthesis.