# Implementation of a MIPS processor in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

please I want the VHDL code of The RISC MIPS Processor Core (32 bits) with some MIPS Processor Core Instructions. Anyone have an idea?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Open Cores](http://opencores.org/projects). This is a great site with several open source implementations of different peripherals and cores. For example, the [Edge Processor](http://opencores.org/project,edge) may be what you're looking for, even though it is in Verilog. Or maybe a [Ion - MIPS(tm) compatible CPU](http://opencores.org/project,ion) in VHDL. Best thing is to browse through their library and see for yourself what suits your needs the best.

Answer (score 0):

See this question [Project on MIPS pipelined processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599960/project-on-mips-pipelined-processor) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17617679/1155120).  I updated the link to the [ECE 3055](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/3055/) course downloadable source ([32-bit MIPS VHDL Model](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/3055/mips32.zip) ).  Also see the Instructions link.